# ISBN Checker - Cant do the checksum

Tags: java, isbn

I can't seem to figure out how to do this problem. I'm getting stuck on the math with finding the checksum and how the code would look.

I know the code has a few things wrong with it and seems sloppy and could probably be written in a much smaller, more concise manner, but I am new to arrays and I am not very good at optimizing them yet.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ISBN{

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter ISBN:");

        String isbnSTR = keyboard.nextLine();
        String x;

        int isbnARRAY[] = new int[10];
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < isbnSTR.length(); i++){  
            x = ""+isbnSTR.charAt(i);
            isbnARRAY[i] = Integer.parseInt(x);
            total = isbnARRAY[i]  * (10 - 1);


            boolean isbnVALID = PassArray(isbnARRAY, i);

            if (isbnVALID == true){
                System.out.println("Your isbn number is valid.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Your isbn number is NOT valid");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean PassArray(int isbnARRAY[], int total){
        int result = 0;
        int checkSum = 0;
        int len = isbnARRAY.length;     
        for (int x = 0; x < len; x++){
            result = (x * total); 
            checkSum =  result % 11; 
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        boolean isbnVALID;
        if (checkSum == 0){
            isbnVALID=true;
        } else {
            isbnVALID=false;
        }

        return true;


    }


}
```

Comment: multiplying the array index by the appropriate number is something that i think i go totally wrong.

This is an ISBN10 chcker by the way

Comment: You are trying to calculate the sum of each digit multiplied by its position. ISBN positions are 1-based but Java arrays are 0-based. The value is `isbnARRAY[x]` and the position is `x+1`. The sum should be just that, make sure you are not resetting `result` by either using `result += ...` or `result = result + ...`. See if you can work it out with that information. Also, you should only compute checkSum after you've completed them summation.

Comment: if i change 
total = isbnARRAY[i] * (10-1);
to  
total += isbnARRAY[i] * (10-i);
I think it helps out a bit

Comment: Some ISBNs contain the character `X` which represents 11 for ISBN-10 numbers, so your integer declaration is wrong at the start. There is little point coding this when it's such a common requirement that well-tested and refined examples already exist- code here eg https://www.moreofless.co.uk/validate-isbn-13-java/ and apache's ISBNValidator here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/ISBNValidator.html - save your time for what is unique to you, or start again but write **pseudocode** first and test it. **Trace tables** help debug code